# Show list at particular timings

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have **2 lists stored** into the database

**1**:**First list** is 3pm that have a stored time as 03:00:00 PM which will end at 12:00:00 AM and the

**2**:**Second list** is 11pm list which time is 11:00:00 AM and will be active till 3pm so the scenario is from 12am to 3pm

I want to show 11am list and  from 3 pm to 12 am I want to show the 3om list but right now **it's only showing 3 pm list as it's 7:00 am** here can anyone help me out with this below is my code which I have used

```
if(date('h:i:s') >= '12:00:00 AM' && date('h:i:s') < '03:00:00 PM') {
    $query   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM list WHERE status = 'Active' AND time_list = '11:00:00 AM'");
}
if(date('h:i:s A') > '03:00:00 PM' && date('h:i:s A') < '12:00:00 AM') {
    $query   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM list WHERE status = 'Active' AND time_list = '03:00:00 PM'");
}
$dt = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Please help me out with building up this scenario

Comment: Any one to help me out please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and use time range `3 PM` to `11:59:59` instead of `12:00:00` otherwise it will check time for same day `12 AM` which is not the case.

```
$nowH = strtotime(date('H:i:s')) ;
$sql="SELECT * FROM list WHERE status = 'Active' ";
if($nowH >= strtotime('12:00:00 AM') && $nowH < strtotime('03:00:00 PM')) {
    $sql .= " AND time_list = '11:00:00 AM'";
}

if($nowH > strtotime('03:00:00 PM') && $nowH <= strtotime('11:59:59 PM')) {
    $sql .= " AND time_list = '03:00:00 PM'";
}
if($sql){
   $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d90fd1a330a83c3b0d3c6a2b64f9ccb845f2728)**

Comment: I checked it with my sqli numrows and it is returning me 0

Comment: Have you run your query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0005 sec)

Comment: I  tried your updated query but still it's not working for me

Comment: Great thank you well 11 am list working tonight I will see if 3 pm will also come thank you for your help once again